# How can I set global RSpec metadata?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a script that wraps around tests in RSpec 3.4.4 and causes them to timeout after ten seconds.

```
TIMEOUT = 10

RSpec.configure do | config |
  config.around do |example|
    timeout = Float(example.metadata[:timeout]) rescue TIMEOUT
    begin
      Timeout.timeout(timeout) { example.run }
    rescue Timeout::Error
      skip "Timed out after #{timeout} seconds"
    end
  end
end
```

This script is in a central location - `~/lib/spec_helper.rb` - and is `require`d by `spec_helper`s in my repositories.

I would like to be able to configure `example.metadata[:timeout]` at a **repository-wide** level, to have **all** of its specs time out (for example) after two seconds, or (for another example) not at all.

I've tried setting it as an option in `.rspec` - a solution which would be ideal for me - but of course it doesn't recognise custom options like that. I would expect the command line to do exactly the same thing.

Is there a way to set metadata for all examples in a test suite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from hacking at the RSpec internals, which is probably not a good idea, the only way you can do this is by abusing an available option:

The tag option is a good candidate for this as it allows you to enter key/value pairs. The advantage of this is it can be set in the .rspec file, and can be overridden by command line argument. For example,

**.rspec configuration**

```
--format documentation
--color
--tag timeout:10
--require spec_helper
```

**command line**

```
rspec --tag timeout:2
```

You just have to be careful and make sure that you remove the tag from the filter or all tests will be filtered out... To use this, in your case you would simply do:

```
RSpec.configure do | config |
  timeout = config.filter.delete(:timeout) || 10

  config.around do |example|
    begin
      Timeout.timeout(timeout) { example.run }
    rescue Timeout::Error
      skip "Timed out after #{timeout} seconds"
    end
  end
end
```

In this particular example setting timeout to zero will disable the use of timeouts.

Order of precedence from highest to lowest is `command line arg` > `.rspec configuration` > `default specified in your config block`.

Comment: "In this particular example setting timeout to zero will disable the use of timeouts." Actually, as you [originally] wrote it, setting the timeout to zero will stop the example from running at all. Fortunately, all you need to do is remove the `unless` clause, as `Timeout.timeout(0) { ... }` will not time out.

Comment: ah i wasn't actually sure about that ... I shall change the answer

Answer (score 5):

The `define_derived_metadata` option does exactly what you want:

```
define_derived_metadata(*filters) {|metadata| ... } ⇒ void

RSpec.configure do |config|
 # Tag all groups and examples in the spec/unit directory with
 # :type => :unit
 config.define_derived_metadata(:file_path => %r{/spec/unit/}) do |metadata|
  metadata[:type] = :unit
 end
end
```

Check it on [rubydoc.info](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec%2FCore%2FConfiguration%3Adefine_derived_metadata)

Comment: Great! The only thing that's missing is an easy way to turn it on or off.

Comment: Could you expand on this solution and demonstrate how this is configured for a custom option from the rspec file and command line? I'm struggling to figure it out from the documentation.

Comment: This is the big winner! Lost a whole hour looking for this.